# Microsoft Azure DevOps Repo: search for a string quoted with double quotes

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to search a code repository in Azure DevOps for a string that has been quoted using double quotes.  I find if I enter

"searchvalue"

the search is for searchvalue (that is, the unquoted version)

if I search for

'searchvalue'

the search is for 'searchvalue' (that is, with single quotes)

and if I search for

'"searchvalue"' the search is for "'searchvalue'" (with both sets of quotes)

but there is no way that I can find to search for "searchvalue" with double quotes.

The question is:  is there a way to do this when searching an Azure DevOps code repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the search bar, then this is easy to achieve, Just use escape characters like writing code, it will let it know you want actual 'quote':

`"\"searchvalue\""`

[image]

It should be noted that the search here is based on cache search. If you make changes on other pages, please be sure to refresh the page on the page that uses the search function, otherwise the results will not be searched.